# Send an array of objects from JS/TS (Angular 2) to WCF?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, wcf, typescript

i have to send an array of objects like this

```
[{"Cod":"1"},{"Cod":"5"}]
```

to my C# WCF Service which i used until today without problems with wsHttpBinding (so no JSON using here, only XML).

The request, POST, contains this param:

```
   let param = "<cod>" + data + "</cod>";
```

My problem is on WCF because i can't find a way to get that array of objects from the parameter of the method:

```
public string GetArrayOfObjects(CompositeType[] cod)
    {//implementation not important because i can't enter here...}
```

where CompositeType is:

```
 [DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    string cod;

    [DataMember]
    public string Cod
    {
        get { return cod; }
        set { cod = value; }
    }
}
```

I have tried so many things like changing the parameter to:

- `Object[] cod`
- `List<string> cod`
- ...

Everytime i get this error (translating):

```
Exception generated by the formatter in an attempt to deserialize the message: Error trying to deserialize the parameter http://tempuri.org/:cod.  InnerException: 'Error at line 1 position 341. Expected status 'Element' .. Found 'Text' with '' name space ''. '.  
...
```

This is the post message that i'm sending:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
  "<s:Envelope xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
  "<s:Header>" +
  "<a:Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\">http://tempuri.org/IService1/" + GetArrayOfObjects + "</a:Action>" +
  "</s:Header>" +
  "<s:Body>" +
  "<" + GetArrayOfObjects + " xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
  param +
  "</" + GetArrayOfObjects + ">" +
  "</s:Body>" +
  "</s:Envelope>";
```

where `param` is defined before. The JSON.stringify of `data` inside param gives the first example of this question (`[{"Cod":"1"},{"Cod":"5"}]`). This post message was always fine with single value params.

Some sites show a solution with a json deserializer on wcf, but i'm using XML...it's not an option right now to re-implement the project in json.

I tried for one day but i didn't find a solution, i'd love to hear some solutions from you! Thanks to all.

Comment: how are you posting the data? did you add data type to your post request?

Comment: Yes, i always used:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' }

Comment: What does the data that is being posted look like?  Looks like a formatting issue.

Comment: Thanks both for trying to help! Please check the last edit on my question, i uploaded the post message and i explained a bit the "param" sent.